# How to Start a React or a Node Application from a different directory using a Shell Script in Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, bash, shell

I want to start a React web application using a Shell script located at a different place in the same project. The project directory structure looks like follows.

```
project/
├── bin/
│   └── start.sh
├── config/
│   └── app.config
├── lib/
    ├── react_app/
```

Here's the relevant code segment of the shell script `bin/start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# load configurations
REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT=8015=$(cat ../config/app.yaml | shyaml get-value websocket_port)

# start the react applications
REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT=$REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT ../lib/react_app npm start
```

The **shell command** I'm using **seems to be incorrect**. Any help?

Here's the error log.

> ./start.sh: line 38: ../lib/react_app: Is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `../lib/react_app npm start` is trying to launch executable `react_app` with arguments `npm start`, which is a directory, not a file.

I would just cd into the directory, like so:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# load configurations
REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT=8015=$(cat ../config/app.yaml | shyaml get-value websocket_port)

cd ../lib/react_app

# start the react applications
REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT=$REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT npm start
```

Comment: In my case, I have to run several such commands in order to start different applications. So I have to cd back and forth multiple times. Isn't there a solution without cd into the directory?

Comment: @ThaminduDJ You can make use of following syntax
`(cd ../lib/react_app && npm start)` after which you won't need another cd to get back to the root.